# Center element inside div and over other content

Tags: css

I have the following code (with [example](http://codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/rcElp/)):

```
<div>
  <ul class="data">
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/800x200">
    </li>
    <li style="display: none;">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/800x200">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="pipe">
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I need to place the pipe list on bottom and center but over the image.

The data UL will have images which will be slides.

I tried the following but I am not able to make it work:

```
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;  
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.pipe {   
  bottom: 0;  
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;  
  z-index: 10000;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 16px;
  display: block;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;   
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJwag . You were need
add this rules

```
ul.pipe {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `position:absolute` from your `ul` rules.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Lj3Ns/)**

Or, keep the position and set the `ul` to have a width of 100%.

Comment: I tried it but it does not help me. See the updated example: http://codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/rcElp/. I would like the circles to be over the image on bottom and the image to be next to the border with no padding or margin. Do you understand?

Comment: Yes, did you try keeping the position absolute and adding a width of 100% to the list? http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dwxz6/

Comment: hello, sorry, the OP asked _"I need to place the pipe list on bottom and center **but over the image**"_. ,so if you remove absolute position ...

Comment: @GCyrillus - Yes, and as my comment after the fiddle shows you can do that.

Comment: @j08691 missed it, you should update your answer about removing absolute positionning :)